# How to add scrollbar to a page

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar

I am opening a pop up in a html page using jquery.
If i resize my browser to the minimum size, I dont get scroll bars for the browser..

Can anyone suggest some solution for this ??
I tried giving overflow property for the body but that does'nt work..

Code snippet:

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#b').click(function() {
$('#show').fadeIn();});});



 click

Hi

Comment: @user did you explicty removed scroll bars??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
html,body{
overflow:auto;
}
```

should work otherwise you have some ohter issues somewhere, if so you should post a link to the website so we could take a look

Comment: When using IE development toolbar, it is showing that the page has been resized to a small part...